# Core Plot: Displaying Right Aligned Y Axis on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have search for quite some time now and found a good amount of old resources that at one point were working solutions to my current issue. However, Core Plot has evolved and the solutions I've found are no longer functional if implemented in the same way. I was hoping I could get an up to date answer for what I'm sure is a common feature of various graphs and charts.

My current issue is that when I try to right align one of the 3 axes that I have on my plot, while the axis itself, title included, does moves, there are no tick marks, or associated labels. I'm guessing what I have is probably incomplete.

Here is my relevant axis generation code:

```
CPTAxis *yRight = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
yRight.Title = @"Right Axis";
yRight.titleOffset = 10.0f;
yRight.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
yRight.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
yRight.minorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
yRight.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
yRight.labelOffset = 3.0f;
yRight.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(10.0f);
yRight.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;
yRight.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
yRight.majorTickLength = 7.0f;

axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, yRight, yLeft, nil];
self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet = axisSet;

//Next two lines are in charge of right aligning y axis
axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0];
//axisSet.yAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive; this is commented out because I havent found it to do anything, though may be necessary for it to work once complete.

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)hostView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
x.plotSpace = plotSpace;
yLeft.plotSpace = plotSpace;
yRight.plotSpace = plotSpace;
```

I have the feeling that what I'm missing isn't a whole lot, but I've just run out of ideas on what to look for and try at this point.

Mini side question, are floating axes supported for iOS? axisSet.yAxis.isFloatingAxis gives me an error :(

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isFloatingAxis` property was removed in favor of axis constraints.

```
yRight.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0];
yRight.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
```

What is the `yRange` of the plot space? The current labeling setup will put ticks and labels at 0, 10, 20, etc. on `yRight`.

Comment: Ah, good to know it was removed. I guess it was as simple as people made it out to be. I had all the pieces, I just had to play with my yRange and intervals. Thanks for the help Eric!